# Use a variable from another method

Tags: java, variables, methods

I have 2 methods in Java.

1. In the first method, I am asking the user to make a choice, then i want to store this choice for using in the future.
2. The second method I wrote only to *call the first one* to use this choice.

Now, I want to use this variable and add it into an `ArrayList`. **Is it possible to do it?**

```
public static void letUserChooseAgain () {
    System.out.println("Please choose an option (1/2):");
    System.out.println("1. Dollars to Pounds");
    System.out.println("2. Pounds to Dollars");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double userChoice = scanner.nextDouble();
    userChoiceToRemember(userChoice);
}


public static void userChoiceToRemember (double number) {
    double remember = number;
}
```

Comment: Storing it in a local variable, as you currently do, is useless, since it will be gone once the method returns. You need to store it in some static or instance variable of your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive, I understood your requirement properly if it is kindly find the source code

It can be proposed in two different approach:

**APPROACH 1**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
static ArrayList < Double > numbers = new ArrayList < Double > ();

  public static void letUserChooseAgain ()
  {
    System.out.println ("Please choose an option (1/2):");
    System.out.println ("1. Dollars to Pounds");
    System.out.println ("2. Pounds to Dollars");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    double userChoice = scanner.nextDouble ();
      numbers.add (userChoice);
      userChoiceToRemember (userChoice);
  }


  public static void userChoiceToRemember (double number)
  {
    double remember = number;
    System.out.println ("Remembered User Choice :" + numbers.get (0));
  }
```

**APPROACH 2**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
  static ArrayList < Double > numbers = new ArrayList < Double > ();
  public static void letUserChooseAgain ()
  {
    System.out.println ("Please choose an option (1/2):");
    System.out.println ("1. Dollars to Pounds");
    System.out.println ("2. Pounds to Dollars");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    double userChoice = scanner.nextDouble ();
      userChoiceToRemember (userChoice);
  }


  public static void userChoiceToRemember (double number)
  {
    double remember = number;
    numbers.add (remember);
    System.out.println ("Remembered User Choice :" + numbers.get (0));
  }
```

*I hope the above code will help you, have a nice day !!*

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a data structure that will keep the value that needs to be shared . Normally, it is done by defining a class that have members that keep the data needed by the class and methods that can access and change the members. This simple java class with members and accessor methods is called Java Bean.

Another option in your case is to have a static variable of type `ArrayList<Double>` to keep user choices.

I would go for a simple class that keeps user choices with a `ArrayList<Double>` member. An additional class would be the one that controls the flow of your program using the input provided by the user.

In your main class - the entry point to your program you woould need to instantiate both the class that controls the flow and the one that stores the user choices.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right you want to safe the number in a array like this?

```
Array<Double> numbers = new Array<>();

public static void letUserChooseAgain () {
    System.out.println("Please choose an option (1/2):");
    System.out.println("1. Dollars to Pounds");
    System.out.println("2. Pounds to Dollars");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double userChoice = scanner.nextDouble();
    userChoiceToRemember(userChoice);
}


public static void userChoiceToRemember (double number) {
    double remember = number;
    numbers.add(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either give it an `ArrayList` to add to:

```
public static void letUserChooseAgain () {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double userChoice = scanner.nextDouble();
    ArrayList<Double> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Double>()
    userChoiceToRemember(userChoice, myArrayList);
}


public static void userChoiceToRemember (double number, ArrayList<Double> anArrayList) {
    anArrayList.add(number);
}
```

Have the method create it's own

```
public static void letUserChooseAgain () {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double userChoice = scanner.nextDouble();
    ArrayList<Double> userChoiceInList = userChoiceToRemember(userChoice);
}


public static ArrayList<Double> userChoiceToRemember (double number, ArrayList<Double> anArrayList) {
    ArrayList<Double> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Double>()
    myArrayList.add(number);
    return myArrayList;

}
```

or add it to the `ArrayList` outside of the loop

```
public static void letUserChooseAgain () {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double userChoice = scanner.nextDouble();
    ArrayList<Double> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Double>()
    myArrayList.add(userChoiceToRemember(userChoice));
}


public static void userChoiceToRemember (double number) {
    return number;
}
```

That's assuming there's a good reason you can't just:

```
public static void letUserChooseAgain () {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Double> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Double>()
    myArrayList.add(scanner.nextDouble());
}
```